# removeEventListener() is not working by React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried any workaround I can think ,
but still cant remove EventListener .
here are all my ways of thinking
I cant think of any other way to solve it .
hope someone can tell me what can i do

1. delete directly

```
function doSomething(){}
const [testP, setTestP] = useState();
useEffect(() => { setTestP(document.querySelector("#test")); }, [testP]);

function App(){
return(
    <>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <button onClick={ testP.addEventListener("click",doSomething); }></button>
    <button onClick={ testP.removeEventListener("click",doSomething); }></button>
    < />
  );
}
```

2. use one useEffect() hook

```
function doSomething(){}
const [testP, setTestP] = useState();
useEffect(() => { setTestP(document.querySelector("#test")); }, [testP]);

const [do, setDo]  = useState(false);  
useEffect(() => { 
  if(do === true) testP.addEventListener("click", doSomething); 
  else testP.removeEventListener("click", doSomething); 
}, [do]);

function App(){
return(
    <>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <button onClick={ setDo(true); }></button>
    <button onClick={ setDo(false); }></button>
    < />
  );
}
```

3. use two useEffect() hook

```
function doSomething(){}
const [testP, setTestP] = useState();
useEffect(() => { setTestP(document.querySelector("#test")); }, [testP]);

const [enable, setEnable]  = useState(true);
const [disable, setDisable] = useState(true);  
useEffect(() => { testP.addEventListener("click", doSomething); }, [enable]);
useEffect(() => { testP.removeEventListener("click", doSomething); }, [disable]);

function App(){
return(
    <>
    <p id="test"></p>
    <button onClick={ setEnable(!enable); }></button>
    <button onClick={ setDisable(!disable); }></button>
    < />
  );
}
```

4. use useState hook

```
function doSomething(){}

const [foo, setFoo]  = useState();  

function App(){
return(
    <>
    <p id="test" onClick={foo}></p>
    <button onClick={ setFoo(doSomething); }></button>
    <button onClick={ setFoo(null); }></button>
    < />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you are trying to add and remove Event listener on `p` by clicking on buttons. So If you want to do that then you can simply make use of `useRef` hook, there is no need of using `useState` or `useEffect`. You can take the `ref` of `p` using `useRef` and simply attach eventListener or detach event listener by clicking on buttons.

[`CODESANDBOX LINK`](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-glade-y673fk?file=/src/Comp.js)

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function Comp() {
  const pRef = useRef(null);

  function doSomething() {
    console.log("Loggin from doSomething");
  }

  function attachEventListener() {
    if (pRef.current) pRef.current.addEventListener("click", doSomething);
  }

  function detachEventListener() {
    if (pRef.current) pRef.current.removeEventListener("click", doSomething);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p id="test" ref={pRef}>
        paragraph
      </p>
      <button onClick={attachEventListener}>addEventListener</button>
      <button onClick={detachEventListener}>removeEventListener</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

You have to pass a function to `onClick` instead you are invoking it.

```
<button onClick={ setFoo(doSomething); }></button>
```

So above snippet should be

```
<button onClick={ () => setFoo(doSomething) }></button>
```

Comment: I haven't learned useRef yet, but it looks like this would be a good workaround, I'll give it a try, thank you ~

Comment: @Kaosu-Niku We can't consider this as a workaround. This can be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using controlled component

```
function doSomething() {
  console.log('Do something')
}

export function App(props) {
  const [enabled, setEnabled] = React.useState(false)

  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <p onClick={enabled ? doSomething : null}>paragraph</p>
      <button onClick={() => setEnabled(true)}>Add event</button>
      <button onClick={() => setEnabled(false)}>Remove event</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```